# Connection string cannot be created

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, database-connection

I'm developing a website in that, i couldn't create connection string ,i have included all the required namespaces but when i create a string variable to store the connection it wont come in declaring SqlConnection object, but i can able to create connection string  in constructor class,why i can't able to create connection outside constructor. is there any specific reason..

Comment: it's very difficult to know what you mean. Maybe you should narrow down the problem to the smallest code that will cause the problem, then post that code. Also, in the future, please leave off the "hello" and signature - this is not a discussion forum, just a Q&A site.

Comment: Some example code would most likely make this question answerable.

Answer (score 0):

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="main" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data     Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;User Id=myid;Password=mypassword;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
<configuration>
```

C# code:

```
using System.Configuration;

public string _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[1].ConnectionString;

public string GetString(string sql, SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
  List<string> result = new List<string>();
  SqlDataReader reader;
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString ))
  {
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    if (parameters != null)
    {
      command.Parameters.Clear();
      command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
    }
    connection.Open();
    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
      string row = string.Empty;
      foreach (string col in reader)
      {
        row += col + ",";
      }
      result.Add(row)
    }
    reader.Close();
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, guys i'm new to this C# thats y struggle to express it

Comment: @candru: Does this answer help you with your question at all?